# how to redirect user to particular link after login in php

Tags: javascript, php, html

I want to know how to redirect user to particular link after login in php
for example in e-commerce website if user click on add to cart button and if that user is not logged in then user will be redirected to login page and after login user will be redirected to cart page which is requested page
so,i want to know how to code for this.

---

```
if(!empty($_SESSION['username']))
{
        $url=' .php';//here i want dynamic link which is requested page link when user tries to access 
}
else
{
        $url='login.php';
}
```

Comment: OK. So where is code??

Comment: actually i didn't get any idea for how to code for this that's why i asked this question.

Comment: may be this is possible using cookies but don't know how

Comment: add your loging code. So it help Stack users to provide an good answer

Comment: i have updated my que.

Answer (score 1):

First check user is login or not

```
if(isset($_SESSION['username'])){
$url='cart.php';
}else{
$url='login.php';
}
<a href="<?php echo $url; ?>">add to cart</a>
```

Comment: i have updated my que. for better understanding for what i want

Comment: can you please try my answer :) @Dipesh

Comment: but still confused because if user redirected to login page and after login he must redirected to cart.php. so, i want to know code for that.

Comment: @Dipesh can you please check my answer.

Comment: header("Location:".$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']);

Comment: try this after login success

Answer (score 0):

You have to pass the variables for your reference to know from which page you are coming.

You have to use `header()` for this.

```
session_start();// beginning of your file.
if(user is logged in) {
     start checking for conditions here.
     if($_GET['from'] == "checkout"
          $file="checkout.php";
     else
          $file="index.php";

     header("Location: $file");// file to which you want to redirect after login.
} else {
     // redirect to login page.
}
```

You can pass from where you are coming to this page, then check that is user is logged in, then decide where to redirect.

Comment: thanks for reply but i know this basic code. i think u didn't get my question

Comment: i have updated my que. for better understanding for what i want

Answer (score 0):

Probably it would be quicker for you to Google this first than to take the time typing it into StackOverflow and waiting to monitor responses, but who's to say. Maybe your browser was already open on this page and you're using an old dialup modem so loading new non-cached content is very slow.

[How to make a redirect in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/768431/how-to-make-a-redirect-in-php)

Answer (score 0):

you can try this one:

```
header('Location: http://www.example.com/');
```

Here you can find useful links to free books:https://stackoverflow.com/tags/php/info

Answer (score 0):

login form

```
<form action="loginchk.php" method="post">
      <input type="text" name="unm" id="unm" />
      <input type="password" name="pwd" id="pwd" />
      <input type="hidden" name="redirect_url" value="<?php echo basename($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']); ?>" />
      <input type="submit" value="Login" />
</form>
```

loginchk.php

```
<?php 
    if(!empty($_POST)){
        extract($_POST);

        //sql query

        if(//true condition){
              header("location:".$redirect_url);
        } else{
              header("location:login.php");
        }
    }
?>
```