# PHP redirect if user not log in - Yii2

Tags: php, yii2

My site sends email with a link to the user if the CO is finalized.

If the user is not signed in the user must first go to the login page, and only if user is signed in then they are redirected to the url.

Now if user is signed in they go to directly to the url, but not signed in go to log in page, he can log in but he is not direct to the url can anyone help with that?

this page url  with some parameters is send to the user to as link

```
<?php
if(isset($_SESSION['ssid']) &&  $_SESSION['ssid'] == session_id() ) 
{ 
      // do you staff, after login confirm
}          
else { 
    // redirect to loginPage.php
}
use yii\helpers\Html;
use yii\helpers\Url;
use yii\widgets\ActiveForm;
use yii\widgets\Pjax;
use kartik\grid\GridView;
use backend\models\Item;
use backend\models\Respond;
use kartik\time\TimePicker;
use backend\models\RespondItem;
use backend\models\RequestItem;
use backend\models\DistributorHasItemCode;
?>
<?php
$check = null;
$checknow = null;
$checkfield = null;
$today = date('Y-m-d');
$date = date("Y-m-d H:i:s", time()); 
$date1 = new DateTime($date); 
$date2 = new DateTime($model->end_date.' '.$model->end_time);
if(empty($model->end_date))
{
    $model->end_date = $today;
}

if (Yii::$app->user->identity->ref_table =="sales_rep") 
{
    $sales_rep = Yii::$app->user->identity->ref_id;
    $respond = Respond::find()->where(['sales_rep_id'=>$sales_rep,'customer_order_request_id'=>$model->id])->one();

    if (!empty($respond) && $respond->status == 'Finalized and customer Notified' || $date1>=$date2 ) 
    {
        $check = "disabled='disabled'";
    }

    if ($model->status == 'Finalized and Sales Rep Notified') {
        $checknow = "disabled='disabled'";

    }

}else {
    if ($model->status == 'Finalized and Sales Rep Notified') {
        $check = "disabled='disabled'";
    }
}
?>
  <?= Yii::$app->session->getFlash('success') ?>
  <div class="customer-order-request-form">

<?php $form = ActiveForm::begin(['id'=>'cor']); ?> 

<fieldset <?= $check?> >
<fieldset <?= $checknow?> >
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-4">

        <?= $form->field($model, 'code')->textInput(['maxlength' => 10,'readonly'=>TRUE]) ?>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-2" disabled>
    <?= $form->field($model, 'end_date')->widget(\yii\jui\DatePicker::classname(), [
            'dateFormat' => 'yyyy-MM-dd',
            'clientOptions'=> ['defaultDate'=>$today,'minDate' =>$today,],
            'options'=>[
                'class'=> 'form-control',

            ],
            ])
    ?>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-2">
        <?= $form->field($model, 'end_time')->widget(TimePicker::classname(), [
            'pluginOptions' =>
            [
                'showMeridian' => true,
            ],

            ]);
        ?>
    </div>

    <div class="col-lg-4">
        <?= $form->field($model, 'status')->textInput(['readonly'=>TRUE]) ?>

    </div>
</div>
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-12">
        <?= $form->field($model, 'description')->textarea(['rows'=>3]);?>
    </div>
</div>
</fieldset>
<div class="form-group">
    <?= Html::submitButton((Yii::$app->user->identity->ref_table =="sales_rep")?'Save':'Update', ['class' =>'btn btn-success']) ?>
    <?= Html::button((Yii::$app->user->identity->ref_table =="sales_rep")?'Finalize & Notify Customer':'Finalize & Notify Sales Reps', ['class' => 'btn btn-primary finalize']) ?>
</div>

</fieldset>
<?php ActiveForm::end(); ?>
```

Comment: Can you share us your code ? What have you tried so far ?

Comment: i will add url destination code. what you need to get idea abut problem?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33514216/how-to-redirect-user-to-particular-link-after-login-in-php/33514268#33514268 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/768431/how-to-make-a-redirect-in-php

Comment: @learnwhat I surely already get what the problem is, but I need to know what you've tried to be sure that you dont just want us to lay some code like that :) and also to find a solution that fit your coding style as much as possible

Comment: You have been a member long enough to know **We are not clairvoyant** Please add some code to your question. Its does not have to be the real code but it must demonstrate the problem you are having.

Comment: it is yii2 application i think i try with header option but I can't think a way to get the link that in the email link to the page..

Comment: **Code, code code** or we will just be guessing!!!!

Comment: It'ss not about trust man i dont understand what need to be add.

Comment: `i will add url destination code. what you need to get idea abut problem?` what do you mean by this ?? Explain.

Comment: what codes need to be add ?.

Comment: yep it is a yii2 application.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Should use **session** to handle login.

Suppose your url is `http://somedomain.com/somepage.php?token=some_tokan`.
So, at **somepage.php**, use session checking for login confirm like :

```
<?php 

   ob_start();
   session_start();  

   if(isset($_SESSION['ssid']) &&  $_SESSION['ssid'] == session_id() ) 
   { 
          // do your stuff, after login confirm
   }          
   else { 
        // redirect to loginPage.php
        // With "header('Location:yoururl'); for example
   }
```

And in **loginPage.php**, after successful login credentials, assign `$_SESSION['ssid']` value like:

```
    ob_start();
    session_start();  
    //  if login credentials are verified.
    $_SESSION['ssid'] = session_id();
```